# How to remove/clear the old game data in Game Center?

Tags: ipad, icloud, games, game-center

I can't remove the old data in iCloud or even in Game Center. I like to play games like Hay Day and Township. I have already uninstalled the games and chose to remove the data but when I reinstall the same game, my level still is the same and won't become level 1 and start all over.

How can I fix this problem?

<sup>iPad mini, iOS 7</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete your game data/s from the game center, you should simply go to your game center app and choose games option box at the bottom. Then, hold down your desire game that you want to remove and swipe it to the left. A remove button in red should appear after you done. Thanks me later. I hope this could help you a bit.